# oauth2.0 implementation using spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I want to implement oauth2.0 in my project but don't know how to make our custom function to implement oauth2.0 to generate accesstoken in our controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to configure Spring Boot with OAuth2: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/